# Strange JSP behavior while rendering a form in a forEach loop

Tags: forms, jsp, foreach

i found a strange behavior in my JSP site and hope somebody have a good advice for me:

JSP-Code:

```
<c:forEach items="${info.moneyList}" var="mmRoles" varStatus="uStatus" >
....
<div class="paperback" id="delete_${uStatus.index}">
  <form id="deleteMoneyMarketSpread_${uStatus.index}" 
      action="deleteMoneyMarketSpread" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="currency" 
      value="${mmRoles.currency}" />                        
    <input type="hidden" name="loan"
      value="${mmRoles.loan}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lcfspread"
      value="${mmRoles.lcfspread}" />
  </form>
</div>


....
</c:forEach>
```

I generate a form element with hidden input fields in a forEach loop. The interesting point is that (only) in the first iteration no form element will be created. When i check the HTML code with Firebug i only find the hidden input fields, but no surrounding form tag.

HTML code:

```
<!-- first iteration -->
<div id="delete_0" class="paperback">
  <input type="hidden" value="EUR" name="currency">
  <input type="hidden" value="true" name="loan">
  <input type="hidden" value="123.0" name="lcfspread">
</div>

...
<!-- second iteration -->
<div id="delete_1" class="paperback">
  <form id="deleteMoneyMarketSpread_1" method="post" action="deleteMoneyMarketSpread">
    <input type="hidden" value="FGH" name="currency">
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="loan">
    <input type="hidden" value="1.0" name="lcfspread">
  </form>
</div>
```

Have anyone an idea why this happens?

Regards
Sascha

Answer (score 0):

I still don't found a solution or a reason for this so i used a workaround an create my Form on demand with javaScript when clicking the icon. Not the best way but it works.